# eclipse EE juno: java.net.bind exception

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, path, classpath

i am a newbie and just started to work in jsp, i installed the pre-requisites and created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Juno, and to test if the configuration is working well, i have created a dummy jsp page named index.jsp and tried to run it. but i am getting error, the details are below:

```
    Jun 26, 2013 5:20:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\Python33\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;.
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:24 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DemoWebApp1' did not find a matching property.
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 755 ms
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 489 ms
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:766)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)

Jun 26, 2013 5:20:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 26, 2013 5:20:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

i cannot figure out what am i doing wrong, or what is NOT properly configured in my system.
thanx in advance :)
i really want to start learning JSP as soon as possible, but this is stopping me. HELP!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should try to uninstall tomcat and re-install it again by giving proper privileges. it should work for you. it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

re-install the eclipse, and tomcat with root privileges and re-configure the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You have another process running already which occupies port 8005.

This typically happens for 8005 when you try to start Tomcat, and it has been started already.  Either by you elsewhere (another Eclipse debug session) or by having started Tomcat as a service when installing Tomcat.

By general principle you should not use an installer to get Tomcat up and running when wanting to run it from inside Eclipse, but a zip file.

If you are brand new to Java programming, I would suggest Netbeans instead (after uninstalling Tomcat).  Their download generally works better out of the box for web development.

Answer (score 0):

The port is already being used. You can do a quick check by changing the port here in this file  `%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\server.xml`
and running the program again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use tcpview from www.sysinternals.com to find out which process occupies port 8005. If you cannot get rid of that process, you may try to configure an alternate port in Tomcats `server.xml`